# Cannot access sender as Button of Button1 onclick on page_load in gridview in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I cannot access  Button b1 = sender as Button in page_load which is used in onclick Button. I want to use b1 of onclick button on page_load in asp.net c#.Note:Button is used in gridview. Please help me out. I will share my code below.

this is aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class phoneLostData : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button b1 = sender as Button;

        try
        {
            string dbAddress = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\mca\sem5\sem5Project\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

            SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(dbAddress);
            myCon.Open();

            string q1 = "select complainerName,status from lostPhnFir";

            SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(q1, myCon);

            SqlDataReader readIt = myCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (readIt.Read())
            {
                // Response.Write("alert('hi')");
                if (readIt["complainerName"].Equals("abc") && readIt["status"].Equals("Checked"))
                {
                    b1.Text = "Checked";

                    b1.Enabled = false;
                }
            }

            readIt.Close();

            myCon.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        } 
    }

    public void Button1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b1 = sender as Button;  // I want to use this b1 to page_load

        string dbAddress = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\mca\sem5\sem5Project\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

        SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(dbAddress);
        myCon.Open();

        string q1 = "select complainerName from lostPhnFir";
        int flag = 0;
        SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(q1, myCon);

        SqlDataReader readIt = myCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (b1.ID == "btnFIRLodge")
        {
            b1.Text = "Checked";
            b1.Enabled = false;
            flag = 1;
        }

        if (flag == 1)
        {
            string status1 = "Checked";
            string s1 = "abc";
            string sql = "update lostPhnFir set status='" + status1 + "' where complainerName='" + s1 + "'";
            SqlCommand myCmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql, myCon);
            myCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

this is aspx.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FIR Lodged" ShowHeader="False">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnFIRLodge" runat="server" 
            Text="Send Message" onclick="Button1"></asp:Button>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Try gridview_rowcommand event. Set a command name for btn FIR lodge.

Comment: The sender object that is passed as a parameter to Page_Load() is always the control itself (the `Page` object). The `sender as Button` is only available in the `Button1` function.